# Going directly to Main View controller for already logged in user

Tags: ios, storyboard, swift2, segue, xcode7.1

I have a loginViewController as my rootviewcontroller followed by the main screen and then other screens. My views follow push and pop approach. What I want is, if a user is already logged in my view should start from main screen else start from login screen, and if I logout from main screen it should go back to login screen and the push and pop structure should be maintained. I can achieve this using the modal transition, but I need to use push and pop approach, is this possible? Currently I have checked a already logged in condition in my appdelegate to set the rootview controller but it fails if I attempt to log out as its not present in my navigation controller stack.

```
if !alreadyLoggedin
{
    let mainListVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“MainListViewController”)
    self.window!.rootViewController = mainListVC
}
else
{
    let loginVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController")
    self.window!.rootViewController = loginVC
}
```

Comment: can you please show logout code?

Comment: In logout I'm just poping the currentviewcontroller using self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

Comment: you should write let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewController") as! UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) in logout

Comment: or let loginVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController")
    self.window!.rootViewController = loginVC

Comment: have you solved it ?

Comment: If I do this, wont the main screen view controller still remain in stack, also presenting will not achieve push pop transitions

Comment: @BadalShah, I have a usual way using present method but I will have to compromise the push pop animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basic use case,  Please follow my steps.

1. In your story create navigation view controller with view controller.
2. Select navigation view controller as your initial view controller in storyboard.
3. Create three views controllers-  InitialViewController, LoginViewController and MainViewController and set storyboard id for all view controllers.

Created sample project for you. Download link (https://www.dropbox.com/s/zk8x7ptg5mzmotk/test.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Yes, this would work but I need to maintain my push and pop animation as well. So if I enable animation I would see initialviewcontroller appearing in between.

Comment: Try to download it [Example] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/zk8x7ptg5mzmotk/test.zip?dl=0).. i have added the animation.

Comment: What's your code for logout? Is it possible that the login view (and all data/credentials) are going through deinit (so lost)? If you put a print statement in deinit you should be able to confirm view's status. In theory, you could use dismissViewController to return to your login screen...

Comment: No need of dismissViewController to return login screen. Bcz I have used Show segue type(PUSH) to navigate from login to main view controller. I used for logout.. self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use. AppDelegate

**Objective C**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"LoginStatus"]) {
        UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginController"];
    }else{
        UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootView"];

    }

}
```

**SWIFT** - i hope its correct

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

      //Using UserDefaults check already loggedin user or not
        if (!someStatus) {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }else{


            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewController") as! UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }
```

Comment: This is same as what I have done, and when I logout it will not go to login view

Comment: Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'presentViewController'